# What does this C program do?

Tags: c, character, arithmetic-expressions

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            c = c - 'A' + 'a';
        putchar(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Came across this C code in MIT's Practical Programming in C. Can anyone explain how this program works?

Comment: When you debug it, what do the runtime values become?  When you run it, what is the input and resulting output?

Comment: Run it and you'll see.

Comment: Ask a more specific question. Don't make us explain everything starting from `#include` onwards. What is it specifically about that program that you don't understand?

Comment: `char c;` --> `int c;` for `EOF`.

Comment: @nAin, BLUEPIXY in his comment highlights that the code your posted will have trouble handling the character 0xFF correctly unless `char c` is replaced with `int c`. More details [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/3866104/5420829).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program converts any input into lower case output.

*You would have recognized this yourself, if you **ran it**, **debugged it**, or just **made a paper test** for this.*